# How to get the column count from csvReader.GetRecord<dynamic>

Tags: csvhelper

I have to get the column counts from the CsvReader of an unknown csv file.

What I've done is something like this:

```
var record =  readerCsv.GetRecord<dynamic>()
```

where readerCsv is

```
var readerCsv = new CsvReader(fileReader,config);
while (readerCsv.Read())
```

and for every record I check if the file is correct.

The problem is : since that is dynamic how can I get something to check how many columns I have?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file has a header, you can use `CsvReader` to read the header and then get the `HeaderRecord` count.

```cs
using (var reader = new StringReader("Id,Name\n1,Name1"))
using (var readerCsv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    readerCsv.Read();
    readerCsv.ReadHeader();
    
    var columnCount = readerCsv.HeaderRecord.Count();

    while (readerCsv.Read())
    {
        var record = readerCsv.GetRecord<dynamic>();
    }
}
```

If it doesn't have a header, then you can convert the `dynamic` object to an `ExpandoObject` as `IDictionary<string, object>` and get the count from that.

```cs
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    HasHeaderRecord = false
};

using (var reader = new StringReader("1,Name1"))
using (var readerCsv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
{
    while(readerCsv.Read())
    {
        var record =  readerCsv.GetRecord<dynamic>();
        
        var expando = (IDictionary<string, object>)record;
        
        var columnCount = expando.Count();
    }
}
```

Comment: and another thing I learned today. Thank you, it works like a charm.